# Is it possible create one js file (like build version ) of extjs application without app.js

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell me if it is possible to create one js file (like build version ) of extjs application without app.js? If I include the js application, will it work in another application? If not, and I build the application using app.js, Is it possible to remove app.js from the build version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using tools like [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) for example. You can set it up, to concatenate files, minify them and perform other building tasks.

Comment: I've never used those, but it seems to me, that JSBuilder does exactly this.